# Increasing physical activity with no calorie deficit or surplus

Tags: calories, body-fat

If a person goes from consistently consuming 2,500 calories and burning 2,500 daily, to consuming 4,000 and burning 4,000 (the extra load coming from cardio), does that person put on lean mass and does that person's body fat percentage go down?

Comment: How are you measuring the calorie expenditure or the burning of calories? My answer would be dependent on your answer to the above.

Answer (score 2):

At caloric equilibrium, the body will remain at the same weight. Whether the body fat percentage changes, will depend on what kind of activity causes you to burn a whopping 4000kcal.

Comment: He's including all activity/daily needs. The increase is only 1500 kcal, which is about 1 - 1.5 hours of hard cycling, for one example.

Comment: Edited in that the exercise is cardio.. Not sure if average bpm will make a difference, but given it is a good deal of exercise, it won't be intensive!